# Jenkins SEVERE: I/O error in channel Chunked connection

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I am using this command for installing jenkins plugins

```
java -jar {{ jenkins_dir }}/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:{{ jenkins_port}} install-plugin {{ item }}
```

above command giving this error

```
SEVERE: I/O error in channel Chunked connection
```

This was worked fine with older versions but with v2 I am getting this error

I did some troubleshoot like

```
JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false -Dhudson.diyChunking=false
```

Still I am not able to success

Comment: It was solved in new version build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-Dhudson.diyChunking=false` on both slave/agent and master sides

will solve ur problem

check official jira link https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-23232

Answer (score 0):

It was solved in new jenkins version build

Comment: Installed newsest jenkins version yesterday, same error.